# How to implement live response that flushes on to aspx (DotNet) page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, flush, live-update

I am trying to implement a live response display on dotNet page. I have a large for loop, that is going to give status for each iteration. Instead of waiting for completing all the iterations, I want to use a pattern that flushes the response to a particular area in the UI. I tried the following code that is flushing the response on to the top of the dotNet page. I this response to be at the end of the page and to be inside the pre tag.

```
// The code to be fixed
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{   
   // Set the status 
   Response.Write(sDefaultStatus);
   Response.Flush();
}
```

Please provide if you have any better way to display the response at the end of the page or in a particular area. Thank you for reading the issue.

Comment: Are you looking for a progress bar?

Comment: Yes Danish, kind of a progress bar.

Comment: There are plenty of free and pad progress bars already available. You might want to take a look at them before creating your own. Take a look at essentialobjects.com to start

Comment: The easier way would be using an `UpdatePanel` and 'ScriptManager' from Ajax Control Toolkit to make a partial `PostBack` and refresh the page section you want.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/